# Unable to connect Selenium 3.12.0 Grid Node to the Grid Hub

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

I have my hub running on my Windows 10 machine, which is also the VirtualBox host. I am running an OS X High Sierra VirtualBox as the node.

When I try to register the node with this command:

```
java -Dwebdriver.firefox.driver=/Users/jlott/Desktop/geckodriver -jar /etc/selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar -role node -hub http://10.195.0.159:4444/grid/register
```

I get the following error:
[node error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9B7u.png)

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what was preventing the connection. I needed to add a firewall exception for the tcp port I am using in the Windows Firewall settings. Once I added this, the node connected successfully.

Answer (score 0):

While working with *Selenium Client 3.x*, *GeckoDriver 0.20.1* and *Firefox Quantum v60.0.2* to start the **Selenium Grid Node** you need to use the following commans:

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=<absolute_path>/geckodriver -jar /etc/selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar -role node -hub http://10.195.0.159:4444/grid/register
```

Comment: Ok, I updated my driver path to use the absolute path, but I still receive the same error.